# Update row_number value in view joined to different table

Tags: sql-server, view, row-number

I created a view in SQL Server that includes a row_number() function. The table referenced in the view contains every record in my database and enumerates records based on duplicate instances of a composite ID. For example:

```
row_number() over (
    partition by 
       composite_id 
    order by 
       sample_value) as rownum
```

The issue is that whenever I join this view against another table (or filter rows based on a WHERE clause), the row number nevertheless always returns the value that would be returned for the *full* table referenced in the view. Instead, I'd like the row number to update depending on the records that are ultimately returned in the eventual result set.

For example:

```
select *
from my_created_view a
where a.sample_value in ('a','b','c')
```

or

```
select *
from my_created_view a
inner join subset_of_data b on a.sample_value = b.sample_value
```

...where either query above would result in a smaller number of records than are contained in the full original table and the resulting set of composite_id would sometimes contain only one instance. In cases where the result set contains only one instance of composite_id, I'd like that row to receive a value of 1.

Is this possible? Or does row numbering within a view create a row number that's tied only to the query within the created view?

Thanks in advance for any light you can shed here!

Comment: To do what you want, you cannot use the view. You have to join/filter your original result set first and then apply the ROW_NUMBER. Meanwhile, with the ROW_NUMBER() inside the view, the resulting rows of the view was formed **before** the filter or the join kick in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to get what I want? Basically, my original view is meant to be a "default" set of columns for a reporting system. I want the resulting row_number to update. Does the row_number() function have to be contained within the query that filters the view (via a join, where clause)?

Comment: do the filter and the join first, then apply ROW_NUMBER on the resultset.